# Pass a variable[Email] from the test Code to a Apex code?

Tags: apex

I have the following apex code that gets USerInput from the VisualForce code:

```
public with sharing class Send_noti_emails {

public List<Inquery__c> u{get;set;}

public String USerInput { get; set; }
 public PageReference sendpassfail() {
   if(USerInput == null){

}
}
```

Can someone tell how to pass the USerInput variable from a test code to the Apex code?

Here is a sample of my test code

```
@isTest 
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass {

    static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails() {

    String MyEmail= ‘Email’;

    Send_noti_emails myNotes = new Send_noti_emails();
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@isTest 
private class Send_noti_emailsTestClass {

static testMethod void validateSend_noti_emails() {

String MyEmail= ‘Email’;

Send_noti_emails myNotes = new Send_noti_emails();
myNotes.USerInput ='Hello';//This is how we set
   }
}
```

If its public setter then you can simply set it using controller.propertyname as i have done above

If its a private variable then as per new release its possible to set in test class using an annotation called @TestVisible

```
public class TestVisibleExample {
// Private member variable
@TestVisible private static Integer recordNumber = 1;

// Private method
@TestVisible private static void updateRecord(String name) {
    // Do something
   }
 } 

  @isTest
private class TestVisibleExampleTest {
   @isTest static void test1() {
    // Access private variable annotated with TestVisible
    Integer i = TestVisibleExample.recordNumber;
    System.assertEquals(1, i);

    // Access private method annotated with TestVisible
    TestVisibleExample.updateRecord('RecordName');
    // Perform some verification
   }
}
```